# DosBox Booting From HDD Image, FreeDOS Image created with qemu-img.

Tags: boot, qemu, dosbox, freedos, disk-operating-system

I'm having trouble booting a HDD image with DosBox. I've only gotten either read errors, or boot failures.

The HDD image is a verified working FreeDOS installation, created with qemu-img.
The image has been formatted FAT32, and it's working as expected with QEMU. The Image is only 1G in size, and is a flat raw image.  I have been able to mount it with Linux, for ease of file transfer. I even was able to boot with DOSEMU, After I mounted the image under Linux.

I would love to somehow just boot from the raw image file, but I would have no problem booting from a mount.  I just can't get anything to happen, and I have read the Documents over.

I have verified DosBox is working as expected, with its included DOSlike environment.
I would appreciate any help, as I just don't have much of DosBox experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was forced to use `bximage`, and recreate the HD image all over again.  Do it from DosBox first, then once everything is done, you should also be able to boot from QEMU.

It is a real shame we can't use a modern tool, such as the venerable `qemu-img`.  Even when I manually set all the disk settings, ten ways to Sunday, it refused to boot.  As soon as I redid the same thing with `bximage`, the HD image started to boot, I had no problems.

This question is closed, and `dosbox` needs to handle disks in the same manner as qemu.  If I can wrap my head around the code, I might try and submit a patch.